# How to create a pivot table

Tags: bash, awk

I have a data file like this:

```
id1    name1 cat1  catname1
id1    name1 cat2  catname2
id2    name2 cat3  catname3
id3    name3 cat1  catname1
id3    name3 cat4  catname4
```

I would like to generate the following:

```
id1    name1 cat1:catname1, cat2:catname2
id2    name2 cat3:catname3
id3    name3 cat1:catname1, cat4:catname4
```

Is there a way to do that with AWK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$ awk '
(($1 FS $2) in a) { 
    a[$1 FS $2] = a[$1 FS $2] ", " $(NF-1) ":" $NF
    next 
}
{ a[$1 FS $2] = $(NF-1) ":" $NF }
END { 
    for(x in a) 
        print x, a[x] 
}' file
id2 name2 cat3:catname3
id1 name1 cat1:catname1, cat2:catname2
id3 name3 cat1:catname1, cat4:catname4
```

If order is important, you can try this `gnu-awk` alternate:

```
$ gawk '
(($1 FS $2) in a) { 
    a[$1 FS $2] = a[$1 FS $2] ", " $(NF-1) ":" $NF
    next 
}
{ a[$1 FS $2] = $(NF-1) ":" $NF }
END { 
    n = asorti(a,s)
    for(x=1; x<=n; x++) 
        print s[x], a[s[x]] 
}' file
id1 name1 cat1:catname1, cat2:catname2
id2 name2 cat3:catname3
id3 name3 cat1:catname1, cat4:catname4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very standard way to do it with `awk`

```
awk '{a[$1FS$2]=a[$1FS$2]?a[$1FS$2]$3FS$4:$3FS$4} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
id2 name2 cat3 catname3
id1 name1 cat1 catname1cat2 catname2
id3 name3 cat1 catname1cat4 catname4
```

Comment: Ideally this is the right way. But OP requested the output to contain data separated by delimiters `,` and `:`.